# Copy value from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do SQL query to my DB. It must search for a row with the username in `table1` and copy its id to a column in `table2`.

Example: Search for user `"John"` in `table1` and copy John's id to `table2`:

**table1:**

> id | username | points

**table2:**

> id | user_id

I'm actually tried this:

```
INSERT INTO table2(table2.user_id) SELECT table1.id WHERE table1.username = "John";
```

But its not working. I don't have an idea how to do that? Could you help me?

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please update your question to include specific details of the problem you are having. "Not working" doesn't tell us anything. What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
INSERT INTO table2 (user_id) SELECT t1.id FROM  table1 AS t1 WHERE  t1.username = 'John';
```

Note : This will work if column id on table1 is an identity (running number).